# PHP Array merge with keys match

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Having Two arrays need to Merge two arrays with matching their keys and rest should be empty. I have tried array_merge, array_diff, array_fill but nothing helped iam bit newbie, Thanks in advance.

**Array one**

```
Array
    (
        [5] => PHM
        [4] => ODM
        [3] => N
        [6] => M9
        [10] => RDM9
    )
```

**array 2**

```
 Array
  (
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 04
    [4] => 05
    [5] => 06
    [6] => 07
    [7] => 08
    [8] => 09
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
   )
```

**Final Output**

```
Array
  (
    [0] => null 
    [1] => null 
    [2] => null 
    [3] => N
    [4] => ODM
    [5] => PHM
    [6] => M9
    [7] => null 
    [8] => null 
    [9] => null 
    [10] => RDM9
    [11] =>  null   
    [12] => null 
   )
```

Comment: What was the output when using `array_merge` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's no use to tell readers which things you've tried, without telling them why those things didn't work.

Comment: why would you want `null` for the other array values?

Comment: need to display in a table as null,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make array with all nulls from the 2nd array and replace by values from the 1st array

```
$arr2 = array_fill_keys(array_flip($arr2), null);
$new = array_replace($arr2, $arr1);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Glad that could help.

Comment: I'm affraid there is one problem, what if we have key '20' in first array but not in second? it will appear in the final array as filled

Comment: @ConstantineUA Yes. But we need to ask OP is it correct result or not

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array 2 to a foreach loop and use an if/else statment to check if the key of array 2 exists in array 1, if so set the value of element `$output[$key]` to `NULL`, else assign the value as `$arr1[key]`

```
   foreach ($arr2 as $key=> $value){
       $output[$key]=(!array_key_exists($key, $arr1)) ? NULL : $arr1[$key];
    }
    var_dump($output);
```

Comment: anyone care to explain what was the downvote for? while it might not be the fastest solution, it does fulfil the requirement, no??

Comment: It's not my downvote, but think that due to `global $arr1;`

Comment: foreach doesn't change variable scope unlike a function.

Comment: @spalsh58 Yes, you are absolutely right. I must have done something stupid when I tested it in a rush to lead me into thinking it won't work without the global declaration. Now with a more clear head, that line is redundant. Thank you so much, I've learned something from this. Appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone if key x doesn't exist in $arr1, then set the value of element $output[x] as NULL, else the value of element $output[x] equals to the value of element$arr1[x], x is the key of the (key, value) pair of the foreach loop (x is $key of the $key=>$value pair). In other word the above is looped for every (key, value) pair of $arr2 to create a new array $output. Since it is a simple question I thought the code is self explanatory, thus didn't include comments. P.S I usually do include code comments in more complex solution.Just used ternary operator for a shorthand if/else that's all

Comment: @SML and for god's sake, please do put spaces when using ternary operators, otherwise it's just like a pile of dust being thrown in one's eyes

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic is this what you meant?

Comment: @SML yes :D also, brackets around `!array_key_exists()` are redundant :P Sorry, it's stronger than me >.<

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic Yes, that I am aware of, that's personal habitat, I usually put brackets as visual aid around any statement that starts with the not operator !. I hope that's not considered bad practice.